# Two joins and a where - Doctrine2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dql

I have the following query in Doctrine2.

```
$dql->select('um', 'u', 'r')
                    ->from('AcmeComBundle:UserMenu', 'um')
                    ->join('um.user', 'u')
                    ->join('u.role', 'r')
                    ->where('u.ced = '.$ced);
```

Always got problems referring to:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 116 near 'XXXXX': Error: 'XXXXX' is not defined.
```

The `XXXXX` is from `$ced`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm really stupid.

The solution is:

```
$dql->select('um', 'u', 'r')
                ->from('AcmeComBundle:UserMenu', 'um')
                ->join('um.user', 'u')
                ->join('u.role', 'r')
                ->where("u.ced = '".$ced."'");
```

Thanks guys for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using bound params, not directly putting the "$ced" into the where statement. Change your where statement to this:

```
 $dql->where('u.ced = :ced')->setParameter('ced', $ced);
```

Otherwise, not only will the generated {D/S}QL become invalid, but you are vulnerable to injection attacks.

Comment: Not working either. Got: ``Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens.``

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. Do you have a phantom parameter sitting somewhere that needs to be bound? You should probably call getDQL() and see what the full query is.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm if the error persists you can try by this way as documented in doctrine 2.1 docs:

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager;
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder;

$qb->select(array('um', 'u', 'r'))
   ->from('Sdz\BlogBundle\Entity\Article', 'a')
   ->leftJoin('um.user', 'u')
   ->leftJoin('u.role', 'r')
   ->where('u.ced = '.$ced);

$query = $qb->getQuery();
$results = $query->getResult();

return $results;
```

Comment: have you tried with the EchoSQLLogger to print the query?
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/configuration.html#sql-logger-optional